# Sample set of search queries for query expansion test

Tags: search, search-engine, stanford-nlp

I am working on a query expansion project and wish to test it on a moderate size query set. I tried to look it up in the web and could not find anything over 10k examples. Can someone post a link for me to get about 1M sample queries.

Comment: What is the particular task you're approaching? If the goal is just to generate a number of web queries, one option would be to crawl Google Autocomplete suggestions, given a range of prefixes. But, to the best of my knowledge, Stanford CoreNLP doesn't have any tools for this task. Could you clarify how you're using CoreNLP?

Comment: I am using word2vec on a set of documents to get vectors for tokens. Given a query, I tokenize it, use the word2vec to get closest tokens using distances for each token in the query. This is used for the expansion. I use the NLP for trimming the set using the stemmer and the parser to match the same POS.

Comment: OK, well we can't help much with the query expansion part or with word2vec, but let me know if you have problems using any of the Stanford tools (e.g., the POS tagger http://nlp.stanford.edu/software/tagger.shtml).